# getting a controlled input warning but i am not sure what is wrong

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, input

I am writing a form in react (which I am new to), and that form opens after I click a menu item that will pass the selected item id. The first loading is fine, but when I click on one of the input and type something, I get:

*A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.*

I am not sure how to fix that, as the places I read were telling me that my component would give me that message if I am initializing it with undefined, which I don't think I am in this case.

```
class EditMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('props constructor:', props);
    this.state = {
      item: {}
    };
    this.itemTitleName = 'name';
    this.itemTitleDescription = 'description';
    this.itemTitletag = 'tag';
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('will mount');
    let itemId = this.props.selectedItem;
    let item = this.getitemItem(itemId);
    this.setState({ item: item });
  }

  getitemItem(itemId) {
    const itemsInfo = [
      {
        id: 44,
        title: 'title1',
        description: 'desc1',
        tag:''
      },
      {
        id: 11,
        title: 'title2',
        description: 'desc2',
        tag:''
      },
      {
        id: 222,
        title: 'tiotle3',
        description: 'desc3',
        tag:''
      },
    ];

    let item = _.find(itemsInfo, { id: itemId });
    return item;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('received props!')
    const nextId = nextProps.selectedItem;
    if (nextId !== this.state.item.id) {
      this.setState({ item: this.getitemItem(nextId) });
    }
  }

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    console.log('input change ');
    const target = event.target;
     const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    console.log(name);
    this.setState({
      item: {
        [name]: value
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="form-container">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >

          <TextField
            id="item-name"
            name={this.itemTitleName}
            label="item Name"
            margin="normal"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            value={this.state.item.title}
          />
          <br />
          <TextField
            id="item-desc"
            name={this.itemTitleDescription}
            label="item Description"
            margin="normal"
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            value={this.state.item.description}
          />
          <br />
          <TextField
            className="tag-field-container"
            name={this.itemTitletag}
            label="tag"
            type="number"
            hinttext="item tag" />

          <br /><br />
          Photos:
          <br /><br />

          <Button variant="raised" onClick={this.handleSaveButtonClick} className="button-margin">
            Save
          </Button>

        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the places I read were telling me that my component would give me that
>   message if I am initializing it with undefined, which I don't think I
>   am in this case.

Actually you are :)))

your state is an empty object at the beginning:

```
this.state = {
  item: {}
};
```

Which means:

```
this.state.item.description
this.state.item.title
```

...are undefined. And that's what you pass to your controls as a `value` - `undefined`.

```
<TextField
   ...
   value={this.state.item.title}
/>
<br />
<TextField
   ...
   value={this.state.item.description}
/>
```

Try to set initial value:

```
this.state = {
  item: {
    description: '',
    title: '',
  }
};
```

Comment: oh! i didnt realize that.. that's right and silly on my part! thank you

Comment: Actually, I thought just a second ago that the `item` you set in `componentWillMount` may not have these keys and also result in react warning.

Comment: but if that helped, don't forget to accept or upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Forms work differently in React, because forms keep some internal state. The [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) provides a good run down

Comment: i have read that and a few other similar issues people posted here on stack overflow, but I am still not sure what is wrong there

Comment: Are you able to provide a working version of the form you've implemented using coding sandbox.io?